# C#: Why does dynamic help determine type argument for use in generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I'm working with reflection to create some meta-tests to ensure equality between two instances of the same type.
As such, I'm using a lot of vars and generics.
One thing I've noticed is that with my generic functions, sometimes the Type argument is object (presumably when it can't determine the type) and other times it's the correct type.

Example:

Generic methods

```
public static RT[] CreateArrayWithNumItems<RT>(RT baseArgument, int numItems)
{
    var a = new List<RT>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    a.Add((RT)DataObjectCreator.CreateUninitializedObject(typeof(RT)));
    return a.Select(x => (RT)x).ToArray();        
}  //actual implementation more complex

private static T UnboxObject<T>(T boxedObject)
=> boxedObject;

public static object CreateUninitializedObject(Type typeObject)
=> typeObject == typeof(string) ? "" : FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeObject);
```

Use of methods:

```
            var a = Model.GetType();
            var unitializedObject = CreateUninitializedObject(a);  //returns typed object
            var objectArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems(unitializedObject, 1); //returns object array
            var uob = UnboxObject(unitializedObject);  //returns typed object
            var uobObjectArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems(uob, 1);  //returns object array
            var typedArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems((dynamic) unitializedObject, 1); //returns typed object array
```

This seems strange to me (a.k.a I'm missing some knowledge), so I have a few questions about it.

Given the same variable, why does `UnboxObject` return a typed object and `CreateArrayWithNumItems` return an array of object?

Given the typed object `uob` why does `CreateArrayWithNumItems` return an array of object?

Lastly (and most importantly), why does casting to dynamic prior to calling `CreateArrayWithNumItems` allow the generic method to determine the type?

Comment: I think the implementations of the methods are extremely important here. You should include them in your question. `CreateUninitializedObject`, `CreateArrayWithNumItems` and `UnboxObject`.

Comment: I agree with Sweeper: Please show a minimal reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `dynamic`, the compiler performs all the type evaluations based on static analysis; assuming that `CreateUninitializedObject` returns `object` (presumably via `FormatterServices`), the call to `CreateArrayWithNumItems` infers the generic type parameters based on that static type, i.e.

```cs
var objectArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems(unitializedObject, 1);
```

becomes

```cs
var objectArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems<object>(unitializedObject, 1);
```

precisely because `unitializedObject` is `object`.

---

With `dynamic`, the *runtime* performs the work, but now it has knowledge of the *actual* object at runtime, so it knows that the type is (whatever `Model` is). The runtime then constructs something *like*:

```cs
dynamic objectArray = CreateArrayWithNumItems<TheActualType>((TheActualType)unitializedObject, 1);
```

(how it actually does it is much more complex; it could look for non-generic methods too, for example)

---

So yes, using `dynamic` *can* be a sneaky way to go from reflection (`object`/`Type`) code to strongly-typed *generic* code, but: it has a cost: `dynamic` involves more work at runtime - additional reflection, and additional runtime IL emit. You also need to be aware that `typedArray` is now *also* `dynamic` (unless you cast it to something else), so *everything you do* with `typedArray` becomes `dynamic`. Increasing costs.